Geometry Nodes- Edge Offset by Normal

Hey, everybody. I want to move Loops Edges by where the normal of this fully selected Edge Loop looks.
Tried to find something similar to my question, but couldn't find any answers. And I don't understand how to implement this with such limited functionality of Geometry Nodes.

Your question will be more clear if you manually move the loop to show what's the effect you want to achieve. The normal of this loop is going where the blue arrow of the gizmo is going, but somehow, based on the red arrows, I think this is not what you want.

I want to make jagged edges, but I want the offset to be on Normal and all Loop Edge, and I want the offset to come from the center.
P.s added a screenshot

Is this double-sided geometry (a topology of a pipe) or just an almost flat ribbon? In the former case you could use edge angle to detect edges to read the normals from, in the latter case you could detect "boundaries" (edges with just 1 face connected to them)
